# Stationarity in an interrupted time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, intervention-analysis, kpss-test

I am using `proc autoreg` in SAS to conduct an ITS analysis and I have a question about stationarity. `Proc autoreg` is able to perform the augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF), the Phillips-Perron (PP), and the KPSS test for stationarity. I believe I have a good understanding of the difference in their interpretations between them.

My question is whether I test for stationarity across the interruption. For example, if I had a 36 month study period with an interruption at month 25, would I look at stationarity as separate parts (months 1-24 and 25-36) or as a whole (1-36)? My thought process is, that the interruption would likely cause it not to be stationary and thus ran separately.

The code I am using is the following:

```
proc autoreg data=one;
    model outcome = /stationarity=(kpss=(kernel=qs auto))stationarity=(phillips);
where  1<= month <= 24;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model specifies some change in the distribution (e.g. a level shift) at the time of the interruption and perhaps following it, you *know* the series is nonstationary. A more relevant question may be how to account for such changes when testing for stationarity or presence of unit roots (the hypothesis being that aside from the interruption, the series is stationary or has a unit root). There are some versions of the ADF and perhaps other tests that allow for specific changes such as level shifts.

Also note that your time series are fairly short (36, 24 or 12 observations), so the tests will tend to have low power. You will thus only be able to detect very pronounced violations of the null hypothesis.